# Shure mic input misunderstanding

Tags: microphone, audio

So I bought this dynamic shure microphone : https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B00FXO5CEW/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

I've tried using it on a karaoke app (Smule) on my mobile phone.

To record I usually plugged my headphone and my old mic to a a little wire with 2 input (mic and headphone) and one output that I plug to the phone. Like this one : https://www.amazon.fr/Lindy-35509-adaptateur-T%C3%A9l%C3%A9phone-portable/dp/B006K11520/ref=sr_1_13?s=musical-instruments&ie=UTF8&qid=1469733054&sr=1-13&keywords=jack+2+entree+1+sortie

Now I bought also a wire XLR/Mini-jack to be able to plug my shure to the mic input like this one : https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B0033YINHC/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Bottom line : the mic input doesn't work when I plug it to the phone adapter. It does work when I plug the Shure straight to the phone though, but I can't hear the audio output anymore.

What am I missing ?

Comment: What was your old mic?

Comment: It's a panasonic something. Unlike the shure, it's a minijack output, not XLR.

Comment: The mini jack output of your old mic leads me to believe (as in AJ Henderson's answers) the balanced microphone output is mixed up with the unbalanced input on the phones connector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure enough I just had to use a phantom power. It works well now. Thanks :)

Comment: That is very odd. Dynamic mics don't use phantom power. Part of the reason that it's called phantom is that dynamic mics don't even "see" it. Is that the only change you made? I saw in that comment you were looking at a usb interface, did you do that too?

Answer (score 1):

I'm somewhat surprised this is working at all, even when you plug the mic in directly.  I really wouldn't expect this to work well.  My best guess for why it stops working with the splitter is that an XLR jack for an SM58 is a balanced signal (it caries two lines that are designed to have one reversed and merged back to get rid of line noise).  The 1/8 adapter you have is not L/R/N, but rather T/R/S so it is still a balanced signal.  The mic/headphone splitter on the other hand is expecting a L/R signal or possibly just a simple T/S loop.  It is entirely possible that it is not picking up the actual circuit that the signal is on when deciding what to put on each part of the 4 segment phone jack.

Comment: Pretty clear even for a newbie like me. I can't seem to find any converter from balanced signal to L/R/N signal though ... What would do the job ?

Comment: Well there in lies the problem. I'm not sure what would do it cheaply other than trying to make your own. What you are trying to do isn't really particularly advisable as the sm58 is a pro mic designed for balanced input to a professional audio device. Depending on the phone a USB pro audio interface may work well, but it still isn't cheap.  Otherwise looking up pinouts and making your own is likely your "best" bet.

Comment: I've found this : http://shure.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4132/~/adapter-cable-from-dynamic-mic-with-xlr-into-an-iphone-or-smart-phone


http://www.shure.com/americas/motiv/mvi

I might try it up ! I'll keep you guys updated !